# Java Servlet request parameter missing

Tags: html, servlets

I'm using Tomcat 7. I have a method where there is a list of names and these names have links to their biography pages. The link is based on their id. However, their id does not show up in the URL. When I click the link the url displays, localhost:8080/Persons/servlet/person?pid=
I'm not sure why the id is not displaying.

I have a Login class which uses doPost to hide the password and username. This is the page where the list of persons are generated with their links.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
{
     ...
     query = "SELECT * FROM persons";
     rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

     String name = "";

     while(rs.next())
     {
        String id = rs.getString("id");
        name = rs.getString("first_name") + " " + rs.getString("last_name");
        out.println("<a href = '/Persons/servlet/person?pid='" + id + "\"'>"  + name + "</a>");
        out.println("<br/>");
     }
}
```

When the linked is clicked, it goes into the Person.java class which handles the biography.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String personID = request.getParameter("pid");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Hello</TITLE></HEAD>");
    out.println("<BODY><H1>Biography</H1>");
     ...
}
```

Comment: What does `rs.getString("id")` return?

Comment: One very important tip what not to do (cause of the design patterns): do not do SQL in controller/servlet!

Comment: `"<a href = '/Persons/servlet/person?pid='" + id + "\"'>"`there is something fishy about your use of `'` and `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a problem with the quotes, try this:

```
out.println("<a href = '/Persons/servlet/person?pid=" + id + "'>"  + name + "</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
out.println("<a href = '/Persons/servlet/person?pid='" and+ id + "\"'>"  + name + "</a>");
```

Your href attribute value starts with a single quote `'/Persons` and ends with the single quote just after "pid": `?pid='`.

The id value and double and single quotes following it are not part of the value of HTML element attribute.

You can use a [Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to validate your HTML markup for correctness.